# Select last_update lower then date less X days from another table

Tags: mysql, date, join, select

I'll try to explain as better as is possible. We have a table with products, all products have a last_update datetime field. and I have a table with a list of suppliers, and i need to get each day count from the suppliers subtract to current date, and check if the last date is lower than today.

for now I have this, that proven to not work:

```
update products_ean p
join astra_settings_automation a on a.id_supplier = p.id_supplier 
set p.active = 0
where p.last_update < now() - INTERVAL 5 DAY and p.last_update < DATE_SUB(
    CURDATE(), INTERVAL (
        select Days_Until_Clean_Stock 
        from astra_settings_automation 
        where astra_settings_automation.id_supplier=p.id_supplier
    ) DAY
);
```

how can i solve this? all the "old" ones need to be deactivated.

thanks in advance

Comment: Why 5 days before today?

Comment: those are our rules, or more then 5 days, or more than X days

Comment: the ideia is: most of suppliers have a period of 1 day, and the stock is cleared, to be check again with the suppliers, after that if the stock stays zero for 5 days is deactivated, but the time need to be checked also with automation, because some suppliers only update from time to time